# Module to support autocomplete for movie tags

Tags: javascript, beginner, jquery, modules, autocomplete

I've just completed a JavaScript module and I've got a strong feeling that this is borderline spaghetti code. My task was to build a tagging form which adds selected tags to hidden outputs to be sent to a server.

```
var tags = [];
var createdTags;
var addedTags = [];
var isNewTag, selectedTag, i;

$("#created-tags").attr("value", "[]");

$.ajax({

    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "/portal/index.php/movies/get_tags",
    success:
        function(response) {
            $("#tags-typealong").autocomplete({
                source: response,
                minLength: 1,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    event.preventDefault();             
                    selectedTag = ui.item;
                    //tags = current tags
                    tags = $.parseJSON($('#tags').attr('value'));
                    isNewTag = true;
                    //is tag already added?
                    for(i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
                        if(selectedTag.id == tags[i].id)
                            isNewTag = false;
                    }
                    //update addedTags if new
                    if(isNewTag) {
                        tags.push(selectedTag);
                        addedTags.push(selectedTag.id);
                        add_tag_render(selectedTag.name);
                    }
                    //update dom for tag_form.js
                    $("#tags").attr("value", JSON.stringify(tags));
                    $("#added-tags").attr("value", JSON.stringify(addedTags));
                    $("#tags-typealong").val('');
                }

            }).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                return $("<li></li>")
                    .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                    .append( '<a>' + item.name  + '</a>' )
                    .appendTo(ul);
            }
        }
});

$("#tags-typealong").keyup(function (event) {

    var isNew = true;

    if(event.keyCode == 32) {
        //get updated tag selections
        var tagName = $(this).val();
        tagName = tagName.slice(0, -1);
        createdTags = $.parseJSON($('#created-tags').attr('value'));
        tags = $.parseJSON($('#tags').attr('value'));
        //check tags from db
        for(i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
            if(tags[i].name == tagName)
                isNew = false;
        }
        //check existing created tags
        for(i = 0; i < createdTags.length; i++) {
            if(createdTags[i] == tagName)
                isNew = false;
        }
        if(isNew) {
            add_tag_render(tagName);
            createdTags.push(tagName);
            $("#created-tags").attr("value", JSON.stringify(createdTags));
        }
        $("#tags-typealong").val('');
        //TODO!
        //is tagname in db already?

    }

});

function add_tag_render(tagName) {

    $(".tag-container").append('<div class="selected-tag"><div class="selected-tag-name">' + tagName + '</div><div class="remove-tag"></div></div>');
    $("#tags-typealong").appendTo(".tag-container");
    $("#tags-typealong").focus();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the whole I don't think there's anything I would have done very differently. However, there are numerous ways your existing code can be improved (but not restructured, so I'm only going to talk about your code in its current form).

So let's start right at the beginning:

```
var tags = [];
var createdTags;
var addedTags = [];
var isNewTag, selectedTag, i;
```

The first thing that leaps out at me is the mixed style. Not a problem, but it would probably be sensible to stick to one. I (and [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/)) prefer the style of "one `var` statement per scope". The next thing I notice is that `tags` is assigned a value later on, so there is no point assigning it a value here. To sum up that paragraph in code:

```
var tags,
    createdTags,
    addedTags = [],
    isNewTag, 
    selectedTag,
    i;
```

On the next line you set the value of what is presumably an `input` element. The `val` method was designed specifically for that, so should probably be used here (and in the numerous other places you use `attr`):

```
$("#created-tags").val("[]");
```

The next line is your call to `ajax`. This can be shortened considerably because there is a jQuery method, [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), that behaves exactly the same as your `ajax` call (*update* - as pointed out in the comments, this isn't quite equivalent. It doesn't set the `cache` option. If it's important the the `cache` option is set then you'll have to stick with `$.ajax`):

```
$.getJSON("/portal/index.php/movies/get_tags", function(response) {
    //Your success event handler
});
```

Let's look at the body of your `keyup` event callback. The first thing that I notice here is the fact that you are searching the DOM for some elements every time it's called. Since `keyup` is probably triggered quite often, it would be more efficient to cache the results of your selectors. I would add the following declarations to the `var` statement at the top:

```
var tagsElem = $("#tags"),
    createdTagsElem = $("#created-tags"),
    tagsTypealong = $("#tags-typealong");
```

You can then use those identifiers in the `keyup` event callback (and the AJAX success callback) instead of having to search the DOM for those elements every time.

In the `keyup` callback you use both the jQuery `$.parseJSON` method and the native `JSON.stringify` method. Since you're using a native JSON method for stringifying, I would suggest using the equivalent native method for parsing too, `JSON.parse`, since it's going to be faster then that jQuery version. And don't forget to polyfill the native JSON methods so you can support older browsers.

Comment: `$.getJSON` does not use `cache:false`. Besides that, I think using `$.ajax()` is more readable since every argument is on the same indentation level.

Comment: Ahh, good point. I tend to prefer the shorthand versions, but you are right - if the `cache` option needs to be set in this case then there's no choice but `$.ajax`.

Comment: Or `$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});`.. that might actually be a good idea since usually you don't want any AJAX caching.

Answer (score 2):

- `.attr('value')` is bad. Always. You should use `.val()` instead.
- `var i;` can go into the callback function instead of whatever scope you are in at the very beginning.

Comment: It's not leaking a global `i` since its declared at the top with the other `var` statements.

Comment: Ah, indeed. Well, it should be inside the callback function - no need to put it in a broader scope than necessary. Especially since the outermost scope in his code might very well be the global scope.

Comment: That's true, although that `i` is being used in both the AJAX callback and the `keyup` event callback. A new `i` could be declared in each scope, but I think for this code it's not too bad.